# Qt4 + mplot3d of matplotlib

Tags: python, qt4, matplotlib, pyqt4

I am trying to embed a 3D plot in a Qt4 GUI (has other buttons), is this possible using matplotlib's mplot3d?

I am aware that 2d plots are possible using "matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg", and i have done this.

If yes, please quote an example.

If no, what is the favorite option? VTK?

Thanks!

Comment: It should be possible and identical to embedding a 2D plot. Matplotlib's 3D plots _aren't_ hardware accelerated in any way, so you don't have to do anything different than you would for a 2D plot.  As far as matplotlib vs. VTK, you're comparing a grocery bag to a freight train... They'll both carry your groceries, but that's all they have in common!  Matplotlib's 3D plotting is comparable to Matlab's... I.e. it's _very_ basic, but makes nice, publication-quality vector output. VTK is immensely more powerful (especially for volumetric and interactive visualization), but more complex.

Comment: Consider vtk - as Joe says, if your application involves interactive visualization, it might be more suited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not the cleanest thing you're going to see.  I've noticed that is it not as fast as the tkinter backend.  Then again it works.

Have fun:

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtCore,  QtGui

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4 import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

class QtMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width = 6.5, height = 5.5, dpi = 100, sharex = None, sharey = None, fig = None):
        if fig == None:
            self.fig = Figure(figsize = (width, height), dpi=dpi, facecolor = '#FFFFFF')
            self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
            self.fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, bottom=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.9)
            self.ax.hold(True)
        else:
            self.fig = fig

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
            QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
            QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

    def sizeHint(self):
        w, h = self.get_width_height()
        return QtCore.QSize(w, h)

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(10, 10)

    def sizeHint(self):
        w, h = self.get_width_height()
        return QtCore.QSize(w, h)

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(10, 10)


class MyNavigationToolbar(NavigationToolbar) :
    def __init__(self, parent, canvas, direction = 'h' ) :

        self.canvas = canvas
        QWidget.__init__( self, parent )

        if direction=='h' :
            self.layout = QHBoxLayout( self )
        else :
            self.layout = QVBoxLayout( self )

        self.layout.setMargin( 2 )
        self.layout.setSpacing( 0 )

        NavigationToolbar2.__init__( self, canvas )


    def set_message( self, s ):
        pass


class MPL_WIDGET_3D(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, enableAutoScale = False, enableCSV = False, enableEdit = False, fig = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.canvas = QtMplCanvas(fig)
        self.canvas.ax.mouse_init()
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self.canvas)
        self.vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)


        ###########SAVING FIGURE TO CLIPBOARD##########
        self.cb = None #will be used for the clipboard
        self.tempPath = getHomeDir()
        self.tempPath = os.path.join(self.tempPath,'tempMPL.png')

        self.mpl2ClipAction = QtGui.QAction("Save to Clipboard",  self)
        self.mpl2ClipAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+C")
        self.addAction(self.mpl2ClipAction)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.mpl2ClipAction,QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.mpl2Clip)

    def mpl2Clip(self):
        try:
            self.canvas.fig.savefig(self.tempPath)
            tempImg = QtGui.QImage(self.tempPath)
            self.cb = QtGui.QApplication.clipboard()
            self.cb.setImage(tempImg)
        except:
            print 'Error copying figure to clipboard'
            errorMsg = "Sorry: %s\n\n:%s\n"%(sys.exc_type, sys.exc_value)
            print errorMsg

####USED TO GET THE USERS HOME DIRECTORY FOR USE OF A TEMP FILE

def valid(path):
    if path and os.path.isdir(path):
        return True
    return False

def env(name):
    return os.environ.get( name, '' )

def getHomeDir():
    if sys.platform != 'win32':
        return os.path.expanduser( '~' )

    homeDir = env( 'USERPROFILE' )
    if not valid(homeDir):
        homeDir = env( 'HOME' )
        if not valid(homeDir) :
            homeDir = '%s%s' % (env('HOMEDRIVE'),env('HOMEPATH'))
            if not valid(homeDir) :
                homeDir = env( 'SYSTEMDRIVE' )
                if homeDir and (not homeDir.endswith('\\')) :
                    homeDir += '\\'
                if not valid(homeDir) :
                    homeDir = 'C:\\'
    return homeDir


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mplQt = MPL_WIDGET_3D()
    mplQt.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: So there is no simpler way to have a 3d/surface plot in PyQt? Seems like an awful amount of code needed to do that...

Comment: Nope, I just used this approach. Seems to work just fine (and you don't need as much code as bhclowers posted, I think he was just illustrating a more involved example).