# How to enable rotation in an Axes3D (matplotlib) embedded in a PyQt4 widget?

Tags: 3d, matplotlib, pyqt4

I'm using the approach shown in the following questions for embedding an Axes3D in a PyQt4 widget:

[Qt4 + mplot3d of matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899176/qt4-mplot3d-of-matplotlib)

When starting the application, I can not rotate the axes via mouse movement anymore. What do I need to do to enable the rotation again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you call something like `Axes3D.clear()`, then to enable mouse rotation again you have to call `Axes3D.mouse_init()`.

Seems to be undocumented, but it works for me! [Source](http://www.mail-archive.com/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg15322.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it after deep debugging. The problem is an inconsistency of the canvas instances. The example code first constructs a figure which automatically provides the figure with a canvas instance. Then an axes will be added to the figure and then the figure's canvas replaced by another canvas which can be used as `QWidget`.

But, an `Axes3D` constructor adds callback functions to its figure's canvas to implement the rotation feature. So, if the canvas is replaced after that, the connection to the rotation functions gets lost.

Maybe it's enough to simply call `FigureCanvas.__init__()` before adding the axes to the figure, but I haven't tried that.

My working solution is a bit different: First I call `matplotlib.use("Qt4Agg")` to set the correct backend. Next, I construct figures with `fig = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()` which makes sure they already contain the right canvas and then add the `Axes3D` to them. I access the canvas simply as data element `fig.canvas` and use it as `QWidget`. It is also important to call `QtGui.QApplication()` before constructing any figure.

Comment: I think I'm actually doing exaclty that, but it doesn't work. Maybe you can have a look at my code (46 lines) at http://pastebin.com/Y7Fcsnpp and might have an idea on what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but my axes would not appear. I called `FigureCanvas.__init__()` then added the axes to the figure by calling `self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')`, as recommended by [Björn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1169818/bjorn)

Answer (score 0):

Here, in Python 3, after setting global variable self.ax I switched mouse rotating on by calling self.ax.mouse_init(). Perhaps it helps you.

```
self.fig = Figure(figsize = (5,5), dpi = 100)
self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection='3d')
self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, root)
self.ax.mouse_init()
self.canvas.draw()
self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.