# mplot3d Dynamic Update with PyQt Designer

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt4, qt-designer, mplot3d

I'm trying to create a simple GUI that has an embedded mplot3d widget for viewing STL files. I'm currently using PyQt4 with Qt Designer for creating the layout and python 3.6.2. I've used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899176/qt4-mplot3d-of-matplotlib) as a starting point and I have been able to successfully implement a custom mplot3d widget. However, I would like to be able to dynamically update the mplot3d widget (eg. Click a button to load a new stl file and update the figure/widget). I know this is possible for 2D matplotlib figures using

```
manager = matplotlib.get_current_fig_manager()

manager.canvas.draw()
```

to update a regular matplotlib figure. But is this possible for an embedded matplotlib widget? Or a mplot3d custom widget?

Should I write I new method in the QtMplCanvas(FigureCanvas) class? I can't seem to figure out from the

> FigureCanvasQTAgg

docs how to update a widget from matplotlibs backend. My code is somewhat long but I'll try to include the relevant bits:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import os
import sys

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4 import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

from stl import mesh
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
plt.switch_backend('Qt4Agg')

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(1007, 607)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.line = QtGui.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("line"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.line, 2, 1, 1, 1)

        # STL VIEWER       
        self.graphicsView_STL = MPL_WIDGET_3D(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView_STL.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("graphicsView_STL"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.graphicsView_STL, 2, 0, 1, 1)

        # File load btn
        self.import_tlbtn = QtGui.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.import_tlbtn.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("import_tlbtn"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.import_tlbtn, 1, 0, 1, 1)

#... More Widgets, layouts, etc.

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.import_tlbtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "...", None))
        self.label_slice.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Slice", None))
        self.label_import.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Import STL File", None))
```

...  Code from Link

.... New file for connecting methods..

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import UI_DED

import sys
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
from stl import mesh

''' CONNECTING METHODS HERE '''

def open_file():
        # Open a new file selection window
        widget_f = QtGui.QWidget()
        widget_f.resize(320, 240)
        widget_f.setWindowTitle("Select a file")
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(widget_f, 'Open File', '/')
        if filename == '':
                pass
        else:
                your_mesh = mesh.Mesh.from_file(filename)
                stl_update(your_mesh)

# Some sort of method for updating the widget                
def stl_update():
        pass
        # Some method for updating canvas....

if __name__ == "__main__":

        plt.switch_backend('Qt4Agg')
        # Set window from UI_DED
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        MainWindow = UI_DED.QtGui.QMainWindow()
        ui = UI_DED.Ui_MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.show()

        # Connect widgets here

        # Import STL File
        ui.import_tlbtn.clicked.connect(open_file)


        # Exit
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It's not clear what is meant by "update". What is the desired feature? What should happen? Where is the problem?